# Is it OK to write or say "as well as" + to infinitive?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Screening is done in order to prevent injury and muscular-skeletal complications as well as to improve performance methods.

Typically I don't remember "as well as" being followed by other than noun or pronouns. Nevertheless, is it OK to write or say "as well as to ..." as in the above example?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly normal and correct.  *As well as* just means "in addition" or "also" or "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I don't see any problem with the sentence construction. Taking another example that uses *"as well as"* in the same way :

> Training is done to improve the personal knowledge quotient of the staff **as well as to** enhance the average quality of service by the office.

Sentences like this are commonly used and I personally have seen it being used by many people. As far as I know (which maybe little, as I'm not a native speaker), these type of sentence-structure is not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I see more and more people use "as well as" thus as a conjunction and a synonym for "and", especially when they want to avoid confusion that many "and" may cause.

I treat "as well as" as adverb (or adjunct).  I would think about what can follow "as".

"As well as" means "in addition to", not "and".

What about this?
"Screening not only prevents injury and muscular-skeletal complications but also improves performance methods."

Comment: Welcome to ELL. While your contribution is interesting, it does not attempt to answer the question, which is related to infinitives. When you have acquired more reputation, you will be able to contribute tangential information in the form of comments.